# Okta, add application to okra user account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, okta

We have a web project and we want our clients to use SSO using OKTA our clients is admins on okta and they have many employees (people) that uses okta SSO to login to access their different accounts.
We make SWA app in our okta account and we want to add this app to [ okta account of our clients using okta api's].
Is this possible and if yes what's the steps should we do?
and if we NO. What's the possible options can we do ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hello, can you clarify the use case by providing a user story?  For example, are you trying to allow users to sign into to the AWS console, using SAML-based SSO from another system?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your reply. I review the task again with my team leader and I updated the question. please review. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Does this http://developer.okta.com/use_cases/integrate_with_okta/ provide what you are looking for?  You can get your application/web project listed in the Okta Application Network by following the steps here: http://developer.okta.com/use_cases/integrate_with_okta/sso-with-saml.html

Comment: Are you asking how to add the SWA app to some users with the API or Python SDK?